# What does the series $a_{n+1} = g(n) a_{n}$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a series defined by the recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = g(n)a_n$ with initial value $a_0$. Suppose that $0<g(n)<1$ and $g(n)$ monotonically increases with $n$. Furthermore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g(n) =1$.

$a_n$ will decrease,as $n$ increases, since each successive element in the series is multiplied by $g(n)$ which is less than one. However, it will eventually reach a steady state, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g(n) =1$. What is the steady state value of this series? ie. in the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$, what is $a_n$?

The solution can be written as:
$a_{\infty} = a_0 \big(\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{n=1}^N g(n)\big)$ but I was wondering if there was something elegant or some tools that could be used to attack this kind of problem?

Note that just setting $g(n)=1$ does not solve the problem. Also, setting $a_n = a_{n+1}$ in the recurrance relation (as one would do in other cases) doesn't seem to yield a useful equation to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that
$$\ln(a_n) = \ln(a_0) + \sum_{k=0}^n \ln(g(k)).$$
Under the assumptions stated, the sequence of partial sums $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \ln(g(k))$ are monotonically decreasing, and so $s_n$ either converges to something finite and negative ($s_n \rightarrow -s < 0$, say), or diverges to $-\infty$.

In the former case, we can determine that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = a_0 e^{-s}$. In the latter case, the infinite product tends to $0$.